# pause code execution while progress bar is displayed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I have this code which is used to display in angular spa application progress bar:

```
Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-nne-c171="" class="ngx-spinner-overlay ng-tns-c171-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-fadeIn ng-star-inserted ng-animating" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); z-index: 99999; position: fixed;">...</div>
```

I tried to use this code in order to stop java code with selenium execution while code is displayed:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeout)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-spinner-overlay']")));
```

But unfortunately it's not working.

Do you know how I can properly implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. As per your code trials:

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='ngx-spinner-overlay']")
```

would match to the *`<div>`* having the only classname `ngx-spinner-overlay`, which isn't the case here.

---

### Solution

You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeout)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.ngx-spinner-overlay")));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeout)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'ngx-spinner-overlay')]")));
  ```